# ArchLinux in VirtualBox crashes (host Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, arch-linux

I'm trying to run ArchLinux in a VirtualBox VM but each time I start the VM it seems to crash. I see Arch booting up to this line:

```
::Loading udev...
```

It pauses there for say 30 seconds, then I briefly see next line but before I can read what is says the VM crashes. I've tried different settings in VirtualBox like enabling the PAE/NX which e.g. is necessary to run Ubuntu server, but nothing seems to work so far.

These are the specs:

- Ubuntu 9.04 Desktop (host)
- VirtualBox 2.2.4 r47978
- ArchLinux 2009.08-core

Crash log:

```
Log created: 2009-08-29T22:28:11.322825000Z
Executable: /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox
Arg[0]: /usr/lib/virtualbox/VirtualBox
Arg[1]: --comment
Arg[2]: Arch
Arg[3]: --startvm
Arg[4]: a8efa91d-d8f5-4eb1-9996-dc023004e0ce
Crash in patch code ff1954cc (c0305dc8) esp=de281d0c
Patch state=4 flags=10c0081 fDirty=4
<NULL>
```

Answer (score 2):

[This topic](http://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=77341) might be relevant